# Accessing container gameObject from component gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. I created a `GameObject` and named it "sensor". I then added a `BoxCollider` and a script (script_sensor) to sensor.
2. Then I created another `GameObject` and named it "taxi". I added a script (script_taxi) to taxi and created a public `Collider2D` in the script.
3. Then I assigned the sensor `GameObject` to taxi's public `Collider2D`.
4. And now, i want to access `script_taxi` from `script_sensor`.

Basically, How can i access `script_taxi` (Box 1 on the image), from `script_sensor` (Box 2)?

[Check the image to understand better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSUon.jpg)

Ps: When i spam taxi prefabs, every sensor object should be able to find it's own container gameobject(taxi).

Comment: If taxi is a container for the sensor (sensor is a child of taxi), you can use `transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<script_taxi>();`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access `script_taxi` from `script_sensor`, you need some type of reference to `script_taxi` inside `script_sensor`. You can then use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). You could also use a variation of [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html), however these calls can be expensive.

```
public class script_sensor : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject taxi;

    private script_taxi taxiScript;

    void Start() {
       taxiScript = taxi.GetComponent<script_taxi>();
    }

}
```

Also it is recommended to follow [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx).

`script_sensor => Sensor`

`script_taxi => Taxi`

`public Collider2D col; => [SerializeField] private Collider2D col;`

Comment: Couple things wrong here... C# naming conventions don't exactly apply to Unity scripts, materials, shaders, etc. These are the file names of the actual scripts, not variables within the code.   There is also no reason to make `col` Serializable unless you plan on serializing this data - it doesn't appear like that is what is trying to be accomplished here, nor can you serialize a Unity Collider2D.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Please check the image which i attached. You can see there, where the sensor object has been assigned etc.

Comment: @ryemoss The naming conventions I suggested apply to his `class` names, not necessarily the file names. Also, there is no need to make the `Collider2D` object public if you are only planning on using it in that script. That is one of the core principles of object-oriented design. Not sure why you cannot serialize a `Collider2D` but it is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Edited answer after OP clarification.

Comment: @MrAwesome8 In order to inherit from Monobehaviour (and therefore use the Start() method), the script name must match the class name. A variable can be private without needing to be serialized - unless you plan on serializing this data, this is an unnecessary step that will just cause problems with a Collider anyway when you try to save and load the data from a file. Additionally, in order to assign the sensor's collider to taxi through the inspector, the Collider2D variable in taxi must be public. I think you may be misconstruing the variable with the actual Collider component.

Comment: You're right about `MonoBehavior`. In this case, the OP wants the `taxi` `GameObject` to be serialized so that it will show up in the inspector. Right now, to make it appear in the inspector OP is making it `public`. This goes against object-oriented design. A better solution is to make the object `private` and add the `[SerializeField]` attribute. This will make it appear in the inspector without giving free public access to all.

Comment: Ah, i understand now. I was not aware that SerializeField had that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Or with GameObject.Find() to find the taxi GameObject like this:

```
    script_taxi taxi;

    void Awake() 
    {    
        taxi = GameObject.FindWith("taxi").GetComponent<script_taxi>();
    }
```

Comment: When i spam taxi prefabs, every sensor object should be able to find it's own container gameobject. That is why this solution doesn't help me.